# Parse img tag using simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php

Can anyone help me to parse the img src using simplehtmldom parser

```
<noscript><img alt="Tiergarten, Berlin" src="http://cdn1.gbot.me/photos/dg/mK/1284593632/Tiergarten__Berlin-Tiergarten-3000000027259-500x375.jpg" title="Tiergarten, Berlin" /></noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this link, http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = str_get_html('<noscript><img alt="Tiergarten, Berlin" src="http://cdn1.gbot.me/photos/dg/mK/1284593632/Tiergarten__Berlin-Tiergarten-3000000027259-500x375.jpg" title="Tiergarten, Berlin" /></noscript>');

foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
  echo $element->src . '<br>';
}
```